# Generate lists of page numbers for 2-up duplex printing: 2,3,… and 1,4,…

Tags: bash, shell, string, arithmetic

How can I generate the following increments?

```
2,3,6,7,10,11,14,15,18,19,22,23,26,27,30,31,34,35,38,39,42,43,46,47,...,135
```

and

```
4,5,8,9,12,13,16,17,20,21,24,25,28,29,32,33,36,37,40,41,44,45,48,49,...,137
```

They are needed when printing pages. I can create incrementally counting "one liners" in bash, but I can't write one for this. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). What are you actually trying to *do*?

Comment: What are you printing?  If it's postscript, you could use psselect from psutils to just print the pages you want.  If it's an ascii file you could use a2ps and then psselect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works.  Save it to `increment.bash` then type `bash increment.bash 2` to get the incrementing starting at 2, or `bash increment.bash 4` to start at 4.  Will start at 2 if none defined. (Made some refinements to where the previous actually works)

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $1 ]; then
    opt=$1
    if [ $opt == "--help" ]; then echo "Usage: $0 [2|4] -- either starting number 2 or 4, to print first number and +1, increment by 3, then continue."; exit 0
    elif [ $opt == 2 ]; then i=$opt
    elif [ $opt == 4 ]; then i=$opt
    fi
else i=2
fi

echo $i; let i++; echo $i;

for (( n=1; $n < 35; n++ )); do
    if [ $i == 135 ] || [ $i == 137 ]; then break; fi
    i=$[i+3]; echo "$i";
    let i++; echo "$i";
done
```

Here it is in action:

```
$ for i in {2..4..2}; do for type in head tail; do echo ":: $i | $type :: "; bash increment.bash $i | $type; done; done
:: 2 | head :: 
2
3
6
7
10
11
14
15
18
19
:: 2 | tail :: 
118
119
122
123
126
127
130
131
134
135
:: 4 | head :: 
4
5
8
9
12
13
16
17
20
21
:: 4 | tail :: 
120
121
124
125
128
129
132
133
136
137
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but making something that just counts that sequence is pretty simple:

```
i=2 # or 4
while true; do
    echo $i
    i=$(($i+1))
    echo $i
    i=$(($i+3))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Using *GNU sed* for its [BEGIN~STEP](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq3.html) opiton.

```
printf "%s\n" {1..137} |tee \
    >(sed -nr '2~4H; 3~4H; ${g; s/\n/,/g; s/^,(.*)/\1/p}'>set23) |
      sed -nr '4~4H; 5~4H; ${g; s/\n/,/g; s/^,(.*)/\1/p}'>set45
cat set23
cat set45
```

Output

```
2,3,6,7,10,11,14,15, ... ,130,131,134,135
4,5,8,9,12,13,16,17, ... ,132,133,136,137
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to build these lists of numbers: go through the numbers from 1 to `$n`, and append them to whichever list is appropriate. The snippet below uses only portable constructs.

```
recto= verso= i=1
while [ $i -le $n ]; do
  if [ $((i % 4)) -le 1 ]; then recto=$recto,$i; else verso=$verso,$i; done
  i=$((i + 1))
done
recto=${recto%,} verso=${verso%,}
```

Here's a ksh/bash/zsh version:

```
recto= verso=
for ((i=1; i<n; i++)); do
  if ((i % 4 <= 1)); then recto=$recto,$i; else verso=$verso,$i; done
done
recto=${recto%,} verso=${verso%,}
```